# Merge JSON objects to handle rendering duplicated info on React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, data-structures

After fetching data from an API on React, I have the following JSON data. Then I use `.map` method to loop over each object and display a list of employees' name on React component. However, `john` is duplicated here. So I would like to re-structure my JSON, may someone help me? I prefer using JavaScript prototype methods instead of polyfill.

```
[
 { 
  person_id: 'david',
  display_name : 'David',
  role: 'Software Engineer',
  workplace: 'USA',
 },
 {
  person_id: 'john',
  display_name: 'John',
  role: 'Frontend',
  workplace: 'EU',
 },
 {
  person_id: 'john',
  display_name: 'John',
  role: 'Backend',
  workplace: 'Asia',
 },
]
```

This is my expected output to handle duplication as an example. Always welcome for a better solution.

```
[
 { 
  person_id: 'david',
  display_name : 'David',
  role: 'Software Engineer',
  workplace: 'USA'
 },
 {
  person_id: 'john',
  display_name: 'John',
  description: [
   {
    role: 'Frontend',
    workplace: 'EU',
   },
   {
    role: 'Backend',
    workplace: 'Asia',
   }
  ]
 },
]
```

Best regards,

Key

Comment: edit the query at the backend would be the most efficient way to solve this

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I can understand the downvote. However, this doesn't mean that I didn't attempt to solve it by myself. You can see I mentioned the down scenario and also have expected output. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let source_array = [
 { 
  person_id: 'david',
  display_name : 'David',
  role: 'Software Engineer',
  workplace: 'USA',
 },
 {
  person_id: 'john',
  display_name: 'John',
  role: 'Frontend',
  workplace: 'EU',
 },
 {
  person_id: 'john',
  display_name: 'John',
  role: 'Backend',
  workplace: 'Asia',
 },
];

let output = [];

source_array.forEach( e => {
   if (output.filter( e1 => e1.person_id === e.person_id ).length == 0) {
    let unique_e = source_array.filter(j => j.person_id === e.person_id );
    let model = {};
    if (unique_e.length === 1)
        model = e;
    else {
        model.person_id = e.person_id;
        model.display_name = e.display_name;
        model.description = [];
        for ( const el of unique_e ) {
            const { role, workplace } = el;
            model.description.push({role,workplace});
        }
    }
   output.push(model)
   }
});
```

You can add a function that sanitizes the data using the logic in that code. like

```
  const sanitize = (source_array) => { 
    let output = [];

    source_array.forEach( e => {
      if (output.filter( e1 => e1.person_id === e.person_id ).length == 0) {
       let unique_e = source_array.filter(j => j.person_id === e.person_id );
       let model = {};
      if (unique_e.length === 1)
        model = e;
      else {
        model.person_id = e.person_id;
        model.display_name = e.display_name;
        model.description = [];
        for ( const el of unique_e ) {
            const { role, workplace } = el;
            model.description.push({role,workplace});
      }
    }
   output.push(model)
   }
  });
    return output 
  }
```

Comment: Hey @Frank Lou Ubay, works like a champ! I have one more question. If my expected output is the same as my new update, do you think it takes less work/code to solve it? I mean now every object has an array `description`, not only the one who gets duplicated. So much thanksss.

Comment: Actually in that logic, the property `description` that returns an array will appear when it has duplicate values. For me, the database structure/back-end should be normalized for efficiency purposes.

Comment: The answer couldn't be more perfect! Thanks!